# JAX-RS: retrieve alternate format based on URL pattern

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs

I have a simple JAX-RS service running in a Tomcat 6 container. Is it possible to display not only text but XML in the browser, in a comparable manner as in Rails by appending `.xml` or `.json`?

The service I have is based on  [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).

Comment: check this tutorial.... http://tutorial4java.blogspot.in/2013/05/restful-web-service-basic-program-using.html 

You can display xml, html or plain-text on browser....

Comment: Thank you. Depending on what @Produces declares to produce, the client will receive the "most appropriate" format. However, the client has to specify possible formats using "Accept" ("Accept: text/plain", e.g.). My question was whether there is some other way than by using the accept request attribute, for example as in Rails where you simply append ".xml" to the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is ***no***, JAX-RS does not allow you to switch the response content type simply by appending 'xml' or 'json' to the URL.

The specification explicitly defines how content negotiation happens - via the `Accept` HTTP header from the client side, matching with the `@Produces` annotation on the server side. So going by the spec, if you want to get a different content type then you would specify as such in an `Accept` header, and that content type would be returned (as long as the server supports it).

Having said that, JAX-RS implementations are free to implement custom (non-portable) extensions to support behavior similar to what you describe. An example would be RESTEasy, which allows you to define the desired content type as a query parameter [Section 17.2 - Query String Parameter-based negotiation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#param_media_mappings).

You could also design your resource classes to easily support the desired behavior - some examples can be seen in the [Apache CXF Content Negotiation guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-content-negotiation.html).